# Larger Google Ads on high-resolution displays

Tags: google-adsense

I'm wondering, is it somehow possible to serve ad-units from Google on large screens and still keep their size in percentage of viewport width. What I mean is that banner 768x90px is OK for 1024px screen width (or even 1280 and 1360) but it looks awfully small on my Kindle Fire (2560px viewport width).

Does anyone have any experience in serving Google Ads on displays with huge resolutions. My TV connects to the internet using home WiFi network and all ads look even smaller (resolution 8000x4500, I think in 16:9 aspect ratio). I can make everything on my websites responsive but Google ads.

May I do something to "enlarge" ads served by Google but not at cost of breaking their policy.

I have tried to find any internet resource to learn more about this and failed.

**Example:**

[image]

This is same 728x90px ad and how it looks at two different screens (right above the page-footer). As you can see, everything is perfectly responsive (images, fonts, etc), but google ads keep fixed size and the worst thing, they are almost unusable.

Comment: I suspect not. But perhaps it is time for Google to create/allow larger ads.

Comment: @closetnoc I was just afraid of that

Comment: Hey! Who says we cannot petition for larger ads?? I suspect Google and advertisers would appreciate it. It makes sense too. Imagine that!?!?

Comment: @closetnoc Sounds like great idea. Especially because today, with high-speed internet it doesn't matter how large they are (in terms of image filesize; I personally use 650/120mbps internet speed so banner-images of a few megabytes aren't problem anymore).

Comment: My Internet speed is much much slower and still it would not be a problem. I, however, do not have any higher resolution screens. All my computers are servers and do not run a windowing system of any kind. The only client computer I use is an HP Mini which is as much as I want.

Comment: 6% of my daily page-views come from displays of 4000px width and greater, 11% use 2500px+. 1% is approx. 8,500 views and it matters a lot to provide large banners where they're needed. Anyway, i have problems with AdSense only, other banners I use are stored in 4000px resolution on my server and I use Ajax to resize them, cache them and at the end serve them to the visitor in optimal size.

Comment: Interesting point of view! I have to admit not looking too hard at screen resolutions. I am the guy who would make the ads smaller for larger screens and ads larger for smaller screens... just for fun! Of course I would not ever make an money... but then again, I am the guy who would make their own funny ads because I am bored and want to shake up the sad world a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en ?

Google offers publishers the ability to use a responsive ad unit that automatically sets the maximum advertisement size based on one's screen resolution, but thats only allowed if your website is a responsive based website, not separate urls for the desktop and the mobile version of the site.

If that doesn't work for you, then you can create multiple ad units of varying lengths and use Javascript to detect one's screen resolution and assign the best ad block based on that.

Also do understand that not all advertisers will have ads that fill big blocks (like you're trying to do for users with a super high screen width).

Comment: Yes, all my Ad Units are responsive. It works OK with smaller screens (eg. smartphones & tablets). They always provide ads in size they officially support but the large screens (actually screens with high-resolution) get their max-sized ad which is too small for 2560x300 or much greater blocks. Example: When my responsive ad unit asks for "banner" type they serve me 768x90 if screen is 768px+ width but it's too small on 8000px viewport. For shorter viewport they provide smaller ads, and that works great. Most probably they don't support huge ad units yet which I still don't understand why.

Comment: Working solution is using CSS transitions to zoom-in some HTML block on larger screens with ad on its canvas. True, when you zoom 768x90 for 5x or so it looks awful but still user can see it, but they don't like messing up with ads that way.

Comment: I have updated question with screenshots example, just to show how their "responsive" ad units looks on modern screens. By the way, thanks for your answer, seems that there aren't solution for this problem at the moment.